# Using Excel::XLSX to parse a spreadsheet in Perl

Tags: perl, spreadsheet, xlsx

I am using the Perl module Spreadsheet::XLSX to parse an Excel spreadsheet.  Part of the data looks like this:

```
    Time        A1      A2      A3      
    0m14m35     0.12    0.13    0.14
    0m29m35     0.15    0.16    0.17
```

Here's part of the code:

```
foreach my $row ($sheet->{MinRow} .. $sheet->{MaxRow}) {

    foreach my $col ($sheet->{MinCol} ..  $sheet->{MaxCol}) {

        my $cell = $sheet->{Cells}[$row][$col];
        my $val = $cell->{Val} || "";
    }   
}
```

The problem is that the time values are converted to floats:

```
 '0m14m35' becomes:  0.0101273148148148
 '0m29m35' becomes:  0.0205439814814815
```

How can I keep the time string a string?

Thanks!
L.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$cell->{Val}` is the unformatted value (which is the same as `$cell->unformatted()`). Try getting `$cell->value()` (same as `$cell-{_Value}`), which is the formatted value;

Excel stores dates as floats, so if you want to format those, you can use the ExcelFmt() function from Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Utility, and you will want to use the unformatted value as one of the arguments to that function. You might even be able to get the format argument with `$cell->get_format()`

Comment: Thanks, but now I get a formatted float!  From the debugger: $cell->{Val} = 0.0101273148148148;  $cell->value() = 0.01

Comment: @LKramer - Sorry, was looking at the columns. Answer updated.